# Create an app like Android NewsStand in Android

Tags: android

I am a newbee to Android development. I want to give transition like NewsStand App in my application. I have used View pager with KenburnsView as image changer. I want to give a scroll effect like NewsStand App. Any help in the same would be very benefitial and hendce i can go further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's so many libraries out there, if you are a newbie try one of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, i found a usefull app example like NewsStand App, u can use it for your app development. (https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar).
check out the above link.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a transition in your tabs/viewpager like a NewsStand application, this link will be very helpful for you to start and go further.
https://github.com/naman14/PlayNewsStandDemo